# lmfit: constraining parameters with respect to other ones

Tags: python, lmfit

I am having troubles setting the min and max values of a parameter to be fitted in lmfit. Basically, I have two parameters, `a` and `b` which need to obey the following constraints:

```
0 < b < 1
0 < a+b < 1
-b < a < 1
```

While the first two are rather easy to implement as:

```
fit_params.add('b', min = 0, max = 1)
fit_params.add('a_plus_b', min = 0, max = 1)
fit_params.add('a', expr = 'a_plus_b-b')
```

I am missing now an idea on how to include in the system my third condition. Can you suggest a further expression?

Thank you very much,
Leo

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty simple, and I should only have read better the lmfit manual here: https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/constraints.html

Trying anyway to be helpful, the solution is given by implementing an if sentence in the parameter expression.

```
fit_params.add('b', min = 0, max = 1)
fit_params.add('a_plus_b', min = 0, max = 1)
fit_params.add('a', expr = 'a_plus_b-b if a_plus_b-b > 0 else 0.')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't actually need your third condition here, as

```
-b < a < 1
```

can be re-written as

```
0 < a+b < 1+b
```

but since `b>0`, this condition will always be met with `0 < a+b < 1`.

But, to answer the question more generally, you would probably need to introduce another "difference-or-sum variable" as you did with `a_plus_b` and use that.